# Intuition behind the $\epsilon -\delta$ Definition of Limits

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, epsilon-delta

$\displaystyle\lim _{x\to \:a} f(x) =L $ well this means that :$f(x)$ can be made as close as we want to $L$  provided that $x$ is sufficiently close to $a$. Well this definitely means that: $$\forall \epsilon > 0,\ \exists \delta >0\ \text{ such that }\ |f(x)-L|<\epsilon,$$ provided that $0<|x-a|<\delta$.
But their is a question came to my mind:

> Why have we chosen to define it that way? Why haven't we instead defined ''$f(x)$ can be made as close as we want to $L$'' means that: ''$|f(x)-L|=$ any number we want'' instead of ''$\epsilon -\delta$'' one? Why we've defined the limits in the way of neighborhoods not like in a way like  what  I've written? Because if we want to to make $f(x)$ close as we like to $L$, there is a must that the distance between them can be any number, which is $|f(x)-L|=$ any number we want.

Comment: What if $f(x)=L$ for all $x$?

Comment: What if you can make $\lvert f(x)-L\rvert$ be any (non-negative) number you want, but the values of $x$ where $\lvert f(x)-L\rvert$ is very small aren't very close to $a$? For example, $f(x)=x^2,$ $L=0,$ $a=3.$

Comment: What if you were trying to calculate $\lim_{x\to 0}\sin(x)$ and you cannot make $|\sin(x)-0|=|\sin(x)|=2>1$ . That is you cannot make $\sin(x)$ equal to a number greater than $1$ .

Answer (score 1):

There are really two subtleties in the definition.

First you need to get rid of the complications that arise due to "$=$" sign . As I said in the comment, you cannot make $|\sin(x)|=2$ for real numbers atleast. Does it mean that the limit does not exist ? . Ofcourse not, you must have learnt in high school calculus that $\sin(x)$ is a continuous function for all real numbers $x\in\Bbb{R}$. So notice that we can definitely make $|\sin(x)|<2$ . In fact we can make $|\sin(x)|<\text{any positive number}$ .

So you should note that your "any(positive) number" definition" has to do with the "epsilon" part of the definition.

Now arises the issue of locality. Typically you want the limit of the function at a point $x=a$ . (More rigorously in terms of set topology , at an accumulation point of the domain set of $f$ ) . So let us again return to the case of $\sin(x)$ and $a=0$ but let us restrict the domain to $[-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}]$ .

Now you would want to make sure that the values close to $0$ are being taken when you are near to $0$.

For example, if I choose $\epsilon=0.0001$ (Recall that $\epsilon$ has to do with the "any number" part).

Then I should not be angry if I see that $|\sin(x)|<0.0001$ does not hold if $x$ is near $\frac{\pi}{2}$ or $\frac{\pi}{4}$ . So for this $\epsilon$ , a choice of $\delta=0.8$ would be a bad one. However we can choose it to be such that $0<\delta<\sin^{-1}(0.0001)$ and see that it works.

That is we need to ensure that in a suitable "neighbourhood" of the point $0$ , we should have that the condition $|\sin(x)|<0.0001$ holds. Now obviously this "neighbourhood" would depend on our choice of $\epsilon$. Now as to why $|x-a|<\delta$ is chosen in the definition, the answer to it has to do with something called "open sets" and "basic open sets" in point set topology. If you read further into real analysis, you will get to the point set topology of the real line and you will learn that any open neighbourhood of a point $a$ can be obtained by taking union of sets of the  form $\{x\in\Bbb{R}:|x-a|<\delta\}$ where $\delta$ is varied.
Notice that the above set is what we call an open interval $(a,b)$. Here we are using $(a-\delta,a+\delta)$.

But topology aside, I think you can agree that these symmetric open intervals about a point $(a-\delta,a+\delta)$ really do capture the essence of what it means to be near "$a$" .

So $\epsilon$ takes care of the any positive number part. The inequality sign makes sure that we don't run into a stronger constraint of a equality which might not be possible to achieve. And $\delta$ makes sure that you are concerned with what's happening **NEAR** the point and not far away from it .

Comment: but why we defined the limits like this why we've defined in terms of $\epsilon - \delta$ ?
is it by definition , a definition we've invented ? or what ?

Comment: I just wrote everything in detail . You do see that if you do not include the "closeness" part and the any number part, nothing even makes sense because you are not approximating it. And you need to take care of the locality part otherwise you do not have a control of where you are approximating. If you are asking why did the mathematicians defined it then this question is more suited for History of Math and Science stack exchange. The definition is this way because it captures all the nuances that arose while formalizing the notions of newtonian calculus .

Comment: If you want more historical context, there is a paper https://www.jstor.org/stable/2695743?seq=1 on how Bolzano, Cauchy came up with this definition. In brief, consider limits as moving towards a point so that their difference in value is as small as we want when the point is moved further closer. $\epsilon-delta$ is just a mathematical language that capture this "closeness".

Comment: @ムータンーオ 
well but in the constant function $f(x)=c$ the diffrence is always the same $|f(x)-L|=0$ so if we consider the moving of points in the $x$-$axis$ it will be indeed moving but no motion at all in $y$-$axis$

Comment: That's true that for a constant function the difference is always the same, but the $\epsilon-\delta$ language show be universial on all types of function. Consider the $sign$ function and its continuity at $0$, for all positive value the difference is constantly 0, but at negatives its is always 1. With $\epsilon-\delta$, the limit at $0$ would not exist, even though $|sign(x) - 1|$ is constant when moving along the positive or negative $x$-axis,